# Java code for forecasting using time series data

Tags: java, time-series, forecasting, imsl

I need to build a simple forecasting program for some hard-coded values. I found rougrwave has IMSL library and JMSL for java but I can't seam to find it anywhere for download.

This code would be perfect: http://www.roguewave.com/portals/0/products/imsl-numerical-libraries/java-library/docs/6.1/manual/WordDocuments/api/com/imsl/stat/AutoARIMAEx2.html

But the library is not available for download. Is there any other simple way around this?

Comment: Have you checked commons maths?

Comment: yes I went through a few of their documentations but couldn't find anything on time series analysis for forecasting